# singly linked-list in java implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, recurrence

I have being given a task to implement the following method in Java: SubList(S, L) returns true if list S is a sublist of list L.

I need to use the following notation when I process lists as an abstract object in the recurrence relations. Given a list L, we write L = [H|R] where H is the head of the list and R is the rest of the list. For an empty list L, we write L = []. For example, if L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], H = 1, and R = [2, 3, 4, 5].

Hence my tasks are:

a) Provide the recurrence relations for SubList(S, L) using the above list notation.

b) Implement the recursive algorithm in Java using the recurrence relations.

Being stuck on this task for a day and a half now and still having trouble how to do this. Appreciate, if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

This is the java code I have been given to work with.

```
class SLLNode {

    public Object info;     // This is the data
    public SLLNode next;    // this is the address of the next node
    public SLLNode() {      // Here's how we construct an empty list.
        next = null;
    }
    public SLLNode(Object el) {
        info = el; next = null;
    }
    public SLLNode(Object el, SLLNode ptr) {
        info = el; next = ptr;
    }

}

class SLList {

    protected SLLNode head = null;
    public SLList() {
    }

    public void setToNull() {
        head = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    public Object first() {
        return head.info;
    }

    public SLLNode head() {
        return head;
    }

    public void printAll() {
       for (SLLNode tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
            System.out.print(tmp.info.toString());
    }

    public void add(Object el) {
        head= new SLLNode(el,head);
    }

    public Object find(Object el) {
        SLLNode tmp = head;
        for ( ; tmp != null && !el.equals(tmp.info); tmp = tmp.next);
        if (tmp == null)
             return null;
        else return tmp.info;
    }

    public boolean member(Object el) {
            SLLNode tmp = head;
            for ( ; tmp != null && !el.equals(tmp.info); tmp = tmp.next);
            if (tmp == null)
                 return false;
            else return true;
    }

    public Object deleteHead() { // remove the head and return its info;
        Object el = head.info;
        head = head.next;
        return el;
    }

    public void delete(Object el) {    // find and remove el;  
        if (head != null)              // if non-empty list;
             if (el.equals(head.info)) // if head needs to be removed;
                  head = head.next;
             else {
                  SLLNode pred = head, tmp = head.next;
                  for ( ; tmp != null && !(tmp.info.equals(el));
                          pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next);
                  if (tmp != null)     // if found
                        pred.next = tmp.next;
             }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singly linked list class in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244871/singly-linked-list-class-in-java)

Comment: You should update your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244871/singly-linked-list-class-in-java) instead of creating a duplicate.

Comment: Hint: define a `startsWith` relation and then use this for every possible starting position.

Comment: well sorry for the duplicate, i wasn't sure how to update my old one since I couldnt find it on my questions. so sorry about that. plus I still havent gotten any help yet with this question

Answer (score 0):

```
SubList([], L)      = true (1)
SubList(H|[], H|*)  = true (2)
SubList(H|[], [])   = false (3)
SubList(SH|[], H|R) = SubList(SH|[], H|[]) OR SubList(SH|[], R) (4)
SubList(SH|SR, L)   = SubList(SH|[], L) AND SubList(SR, L) (5)
```

In english, it means that if L contains the first element of your sublist S AND that it contains the remaining elements of the sublist, then your SubList method is gonna return true.

The recursion here visible on the 4th and 5th lines, where you see that we are invoking the same function again and again until SR contains only one element.

Ex:

```
L = [1,2,5]
S = [1,5]
SubList(S, L) = SubList([1,5], [1,2,5])
= SubList(1|[5], 1|[2,5]) (4+5)
= SubList(1|[], 1|[2,5]) AND SubList([5], 1|[2,5])
= SubList(1|[], 1|[2,5]) AND (SubList(5|[], 1|[]) OR SubList(5|[], [2,5]))
= SubList(1|[], 1|[2,5]) AND (SubList(5|[], 1|[]) OR (SubList(5|[], 2|[]) OR SubList(5|[], [5])))
= SubList(1|[], 1|[2,5]) AND (SubList(5|[], 1|[]) OR (SubList(5|[], 2|[]) OR SubList(5|[], 5|[])))
= true AND (false OR (false OR true))
= true AND true 
= true
```

Possible Java implementation:

```
public SLList(SLNode h) {
   this.head = h;
}

public SLList singletonList(SLNode n) {
    return new SLList(new SLNode(n.info));
}

public SLList remainingList(SLNode n) {
    if(n == null) return new SLList();
    return new SLList(n);
}

private static boolean subList(SLList s, SLList l) {
   if(s.isEmpty()) return true;
   if(l.isEmpty()) return false;
   if(s.head.next == null && l.first().equals(s.first())) return true;
   return (subList(singletonList(s.head), singletonList(l.head)) || 
     subList(singletonList(s.head), remainingList(l.head.next))) && 
     subList(remainingList(s.head.next), l);
}
```

I haven't tested the code, there might be some null checks missing but the important thing is that you get the idea of how recursion works.

Comment: Thank you for the help, explained it better than my prac teacher. I tried to implement the recursion but can't seem to implement it. my code look horrendous what I have right now. Hate to ask but could you please show me how to implement it? Not really good at implementing the program, but I get the theory. It would be most appreciated thank you.